# CodeSigning Error

Tags: iphone, ios4

When a build and go my iPhone app this error shows up:

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I have added my provisioning profile and my certificate so I dont know why it is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected the correct profile in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I moved a development environment from iMac to Macbook Air. With provisioning profiles and certificate, I also exported "developer profile" from previous environment's XCode's organizer. Then I imported it in new machine.

If this is not the case, did you download a keychain correctly and add it into "Keychain Access" so you can see "iPhone Developer: your name..." in "My Certificates" category of "Keychain Access"?

Edit:
Here's an Apple techincal Q&A about CodeSigning Error. (this was not helpful though in my case)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1618.html

Answer (score 0):

As WrightsCS has already said, have you double clicked the target in your project and selected correct profile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the right provision in your project build settings; double verify that your profiles in keychain access are correct, if its correct you should see the profile and also the user its attached to, which is usually your mac's username. 
I have had situations where i have installed the profile and provision, but for some reason the provision is not attached to the right profile. If everything looks right, its a better idea to start from scratch by recreating the profiles/provisions.

Looking at your error its most likely that the provision is not attached properly to the profile.